# Convert a csv file from cp850 into cp1252, without deleting the source file

Tags: c#, excel, csv, encoding, codepages

i have a file which i want to use in cp1252 but it seems unnecessary confusing. I don't want to work with multiple files.

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\file_src.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding(850));
File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\file_enc.csv", content, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
File.Delete(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\file_src.csv");
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\file_enc.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
        {
          ...
        }
```

is there a easier way to use the source data in the needed codepage?

Comment: Are you trying to convert the file into a different codepage so it can be processed by another application, or do you plan to process the file yourself?

Comment: i want to process the file. The csv is compared to files from an ftp server to write it into a filtered final Excel file.

Comment: As example:
in the csv is written name;dtmLastImport, while the ftp server has files with the name;dtmLastImport.
Now i will check which name has a import gap.